# Why i can't get an elements from Set by using For Loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, set, hashset

I have a problem in my mind, why i can't get an element from Set by using normal For Loop, but when i use Enhanced For Loop all things work normal.
Example :

```java
private static Set<HeavenlyBody> planets = new HashSet<>();

for (HeavenlyBody getPlanet : planets){
     System.out.println("\t"+getPlanet.getName()+": "+getPlanet.getOrbitalPeriod());
}
```

How getPplanet object in Enhanced For Loop can get the element if Set doesn't have that technique? and how can i do it by normal For Loop?
Best Regards

Comment: can you share which case is not working?

Comment: Set does NOT support indexes or positions of it’s elements.

Comment: @YCF_L Everything work well, i am just asking how for each works in this situtation if Set doesn't support indexes

Comment: @Deadpool I know, but how For Each works in this situation if Set doesn't support indexes etc?

Comment: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Comment: @Deadpool i will read it thank you

Comment: @Eritrean i will read it thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brief answer is: 
The Set implements Iterable, it is why its possible to iterate via elements with for loop

The NORMAL for loop doesn't work, because Set doesn't have get() method. And the reason why it is ommited, is in datastructure onto Set is built